# Toggle class and slider photos

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with toogling the class.

Here´s my code:

`http://jsfiddle.net/h1x52v5b/2/`

I need remove class in first child of Ul. So, i set up:

```
var len=titles.length, currentItem=0; (fifth line)
```

to

```
var len=titles.length, currentItem=-1; .
```

Toogling of class works well, but my next code:

```
jQuery('.feauture_picture_obor').each(function(i,ele){
        if (jQuery(this).attr("data-id") == data) { jQuery(this).addClass("activeimg"); }
    })
```

don´t work anymore and if I alert the var "data", it shows style "undefined".

In first case, with currentItem=0 works alerting fine (but showing still first "data").

Have someone any fixes of this, please? :).

Comment: If you change currentIndex to -1, `titles[currentItem]` will be undefined so toggleClass line 7 will do nothing.

Comment: Yes, it did, what you write. But how I can toogleClas of first element of unordered list? (sorry, i am jQuery beginner a bad english speaker).

Comment: To do what you want, I think you could add `jQuery(titles[0]).toggleClass('activeli');` before the function `showTitle` is called for the first time. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/h1x52v5b/3/

Comment: Bali, thanks for reply, but I test it, and still show "undefined". Code works as same as i use -1 for currentItem.

Comment: Where does it show undefined ? Can you send exactly the code you use to get it ?

Comment: I don´t know why. But if I test it on the "wrong code" first hightlited Item - it works perfect, and show me the right value of attribute. So code of reading attribute is right. I think, that mistake must be in the function "show title".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sysline at webtrh.cz:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    var $cur = jQuery('#skola').find('li.activeli:first');
    var $next = !$cur.next().length ? jQuery('#skola').find('li:first') : $cur.next();
    var did = $next.attr('data-id');
    jQuery('#skola').find('li').removeClass('activeli');
    $next.addClass('activeli');
    jQuery('div.feauture_picture_obor').removeClass('activeimg');     
    jQuery('div.feauture_picture_obor[data-id=' + did + ']').addClass('activeimg');
}, 4000);
```

});